# Android Studio NDK OpenCV: c++ code can't work with Mat

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk

I included OpenCV to my native code in the app in Android Studio. And wrote a test function:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_atapy_wisetrend3_MainActivity_Search(JNIEnv *env, jclass type, cv::Mat image,cv::Mat croppedImage) 
{
    croppedImage = image;
    return 1;
}
```

But when I call the function Search, execution of the calling function in Java stops without any errors. In logcat I have this message:

> "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x11c00041 (code=1), thread 16754
>   (tapy.wisetrend3)".

If I erase the line `"croppedImage = image"` the function succeeds and returns 1. This happens with all operations with Mat.

What does it mean?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But `cv::Mat` is essentially a wrapper of the actual `Mat.data`. Usually, one doesn't want do direct assignment `image=croppedImage`, specially when they are passed argument.

If you want to copy the image data, `croppedImage.copyTo(image)` is the way to go.